# `this` being undefined on object method when called as a react component prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have this React Component (using Mobx, stores etc.):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { observable } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import Counter from './../components/counter';

const CountStore = {
  numbr: observable(1),
  get by100() {
    return this.numbr * 100;
  },
  updateNumber(e) {
    console.log(this);
    if ((e.target.value >= 1) && (e.target.value <= 10)) {
      this.numbr = e.target.value;
    } else this.numbr = 'A number between 1 and 10, idiot';
  },
  get numberValue() {
    return parseInt(this.numbr, 10);
  },
};

CountStore.updateNumber();

export default observer(() => <Counter store={CountStore} />,
);
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import DevTools from 'mobx-react-devtools';

export default observer(({store}) => (

  <div className="wrapper">
    <DevTools />
    <h5>Type a number between 1-10: {store.numberValue}</h5>
    <input type="text" onChange={store.updateNumber} />
    <h5>Computed value: {props.store.by100}</h5>
  </div>
  ),
);
```

of course the store should be put into a separate file, I added it there for clarity. The problem is when the "updateNumber" function is executed `this` results undefined. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a scoping problem, your context for `this` isn't bound to `updateNumber`

Answer (score 2):

You use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass `this` as context to `updateNumber` function:

```
<input type="text" onChange={store.updateNumber.bind(this) } />
```

Comment: I already tried that, I'm using Next.js and doing so would result in the following error: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: Try adding one more `()`, like this: `onChange={store.updateNumber.bind(this)()` if works I will edit my answer.

Comment: See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvoZQd?editors=0011) with a example about how to bind `this` as context to `handleClick` and using `e` (event) at same time. Basically what you need is do the bind in the constructor as shown in the codepen example.

Comment: Use an arrow function `updateNumber = (e) => {}` instead of `updateNumber(e) {}`

Comment: BrunoPeres Thanks for the help but I'm not using classes but stateless functional components, @Dan I can't use the arrow function because "this" wouldn't be defined inside the arrow fn and I couldn't manipulate this.numbr...

Comment: You should read up about arrow functions and lexical scoping. If you use an arrow function, you don't have to use `.bind()`, because `this` inside of the function refers to the outer scope (which is CountStore)

Comment: Dan, as I told you before an arrow function wouldn't make me access this.numbr inside the CountStore object... You should read up the code before trying to help. If you have an object like this: Obj = { prop: 1, method: () => { console.log(this.prop) } } this.prop will result undefined inside of the arrow function... try it yourself lol

Answer (score 1):

I came to a solution using

```js
<input type="text" onChange="{e => store.updateNumber(e)} />
```